# Firefox Developer Tools - How to test/ simulate high DPI screens?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

My setup: I develop on a 2560x1440 px monitor with a Windows 10 scaling of 125%.

My question/ desire: I want to test a webapp on several specified screen sizes; e.g.,

- 11"
- FHD, 1920x1080 px, (16:9)

When I enter the development tools of firefox (latest version) I have the ability to specify a screen size, see image below. However, this results in a FHD area on my screen that is bigger than 11".

**What I need is to have a 11" large test area for my webapp on my screen that has the exact measures like in real world (11" FHD 16:9)**. Changing the DPR value has no impact.

[image]

Comment: Can you do what you want in Chrome?

Comment: unfortunately not